# VTK Error setting 'vertexMC' in shader VAO and EGL_BAD_DISPLAY

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, vtk

I am trying to write my own `InteractorStyle` for android. So far I was successful in changing what I wanted to change and creating it. Now I wanted to add a function that could handle a given rotation/translation given as a parameter.
Here goes the function:

```
void myfunction(double* rotation, double* translation){
    vtkProp3D* prop3D = actor ; // Actor is a variable of the class
    vtkTransform* t = vtkTransform::New();
    t->Identity();
    t->RotateX(rotation[0]);
    t->RotateY(rotation[1]);
    t->RotateZ(rotation[2]);

    prop3D->SetUserMatrix(t->GetMatrix());

    vtkRenderWindowInteractor *rwi = this->Interactor;
    rwi->Render();
}
```

My previous code was working just fine, but now when I call this function I get the following errors:

```
E/VTK     ( 6271): ERROR: In /Users/....../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 1413
E/VTK     ( 6271): vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0x4b8e6e90): Error setting 'vertexMC' in shader VAO.
E/VTK     ( 6271): ERROR: In /Users/....../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 1421
E/VTK     ( 6271): vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0x4b8e6e90): Error setting 'normalMC' in shader VAO.
E/VTK     ( 6271): ERROR: In /Users/....../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 1413
E/VTK     ( 6271): vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0x4b8e6e90): Error setting 'vertexMC' in shader VAO.
E/VTK     ( 6271): ERROR: In /Users/....../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 1421
E/VTK     ( 6271): vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0x4b8e6e90): Error setting 'normalMC' in shader VAO.
E/libEGL  ( 6271): validate_display:254 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/VTK     ( 6271): ERROR: In /Users/....../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 1413
E/VTK     ( 6271): vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper (0x4b8e6e90): Error setting 'vertexMC' in shader VAO.
E/VTK     ( 6271): ERROR: In /Users/....../Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 142
```

Note that the application does not crash and that my actor is rotated (by a fixed rotation even if I change the values) and that if I start a normal interaction with the actor again the application works just fine.
Noteworthy, the values I pass to the different functions look just fine to me like:

```
Rotation[0] = 0.586671, Rotation[1] = 0.021346, Rotation[2] = -0.028796
```

I was therefore wondering what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An error on setting an OpenGL attribute in VTK can be due to the attribute not being used by the shader program or I believe trying to set the attribute with no data. Maybe other reasons as well. Seeing the shader code at the time the error occurs is the first step. You can uncomment vtkOpenGL2PolyDataMapper.cxx in ReplaceShaderValues to print out the shaders.  Also as a FYI you are leaking the vtkTransform currently and you should be able to call SetUserMatrix directly on actor (assuming it is a vtkActor) as it is a subclass of vtkProp3D.

Comment: Yup I know I'm leaking the vtkTransform in the above code, I just figured it was not relevant to the problem so I did not copy that part. What lines do you advise to uncomment exactly? Not sure I'm following you there. Also it does seem weird to me that this function gives me errors with the shaders while Prop3DTransform() (that is the same one as vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor) does not